# Spring boot Redis get null in another project

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I have two projects that use Spring boot with Redis. In the first project, I have saved data into Redis cache.
Then, in the second project, when I get data from Redis that I saved in project one it is always null, and project one is also null when I try to get data from Redis that I have saved in project two.

**Both projects use the dto as below.**

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(content = Include.NON_NULL)
public class AccountDto implements Serializable {

    @JsonIgnore
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2006838697507278668L;

    @JsonProperty("account_no")
    private String accountNo;

    @JsonProperty("account_type")
    private String accountType;

    @JsonProperty("customer_no")
    private String customerNO;

    @JsonProperty("entity_code")
    private String entityCode;
    
    @JsonProperty("auth_stat")
    private String authStat;

    @JsonProperty("create_at")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createAt;
 
}
```

**Redis configuration**

```
@Configuration
@RefreshScope
@EnableRedisRepositories 
public class RedisConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.redis.host: ''}")
    private String redisHost;

    @Value("${spring.redis.port: ''}")
    private int redisPort;

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration configuration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        configuration.setHostName(redisHost);
        configuration.setPort(redisPort);
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(configuration);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    return template;
}
```

}

**This class I have created two methods, one for saving and getting data from Redis**

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class AccountDtoCache {

    private static final String HASH_KEY_ACCOUNT = "Account";
    private static HashOperations<String, String, AccountDto> hashOperations;
    private final RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    private synchronized void init() {
        hashOperations = redisTemplate.opsForHash();
    }

    public void save(AccountDto account) {
        hashOperations.put(HASH_KEY_ACCOUNT, account.getAccountNo(), account);
    }
    
    public static AccountDto getByAccountNo(String account) {
        return hashOperations.get(HASH_KEY_ACCOUNT, account);
    }

}
```

**I try to get data from Redis as below.**
When I debug, it's always null in other projects, but it's working with the same project that I have saved data into Redis.

```
AccountDtoCache.getByAccountNo("accountNo");
```

**I fixed the issue above with two steps as below**

- I changed both of the projects package names to the same package name
- Redis config

```
    @Bean
        public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
            RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
            GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer serializer = new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer();
            template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
            template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
            template.setValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
            template.setHashKeySerializer(serializer);
            template.setHashValueSerializer(serializer);
            return template;
        }
```

Comment: Can you attach Entity classes from two projects?

Comment: Hi @VictorLevin, I have updated my question as above. Do you have any idea about this problem?